# Что означает выражение в ES6 component<component>?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Что означают такие выражения, нигде не могу найти

```js
import { someFuncOrClass } from 'lib';
import { otherClass } from 'lib';

const a = someFuncOrClass<otherClass>({...data});
```

Comment: это не `es6`. В javascript нет generic.

Comment: [Generics в typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Comment: [Generics в Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/)

Comment: Так же есть статьи по [Generics в TypeScript](https://canonium.com/articles/typescript-generics) и [Generics в Flow](https://code-examples.net/ru/docs/flow/types/generics) на русском.

Comment: Спасибо, понял что это Flow.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { someFuncOrClass } from 'lib';
import { otherClass } from 'lib';
```

Значит из lib у вас импортированы otherClass и someFuncOrClass.
Посмотрите что в исходном файле и все встанет на свои места.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то автор вопроса спрашивает про `const a = someFuncOrClass<otherClass>({...data});`, а конкретно про `someFuncOrClass<otherClass>`

Comment: Да, интересует именно эта строчка const a = someFuncOrClass<otherClass>({...data});